# Objective-C Ceil() not returning correct values

Tags: objective-c, ios, ceil

The following code is returning an unexpected (and wrong value).

```
x1 = ceil(ceil(ceil(100*1.0f)*1.0f)*1.1f);
```

It is returning 111 not 110. I am aware that multiplying a number by 1 is pointless, but those 1's are not always ones. When they are other values the function works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ceilf` operator fixed it for me:

```
float x1 = ceilf(ceilf(ceilf(100*1.0f)*1.0f)*1.1f);
NSLog(@"%f",x1); // 110
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of floating point errors. 1.1f is probably really something like 1.100056778.

This means that 100 * 1.100056778 = 110.0056778. And the `ceil` of that number is 111.

Comment: Ahh true. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: 1.1f is 1.10000002384185791015625 exactly (in IEEE 754).

Comment: @robmayoff OK - I was just making an example to make a point. Good to know. Did you have that memorized? How many digits of *pi* do you know? :)

Comment: Seventeen. How about you? Actually, there are several IEEE 754 converters out there on the web. Like [this one](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).